# Actor accessing things out of scope

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm using the Akka libraries.

What happens when multiple actors call a function on an object? Would this block other actors from accessing the object?

The reason I ask this is because I want to use JBCrypt with akka actors. And since we can encrypt multiple strings concurrently I have each actor calling JBcrypt.hash(...). Not sure how it works since I think, in scala, objects exist in one place, and I feel like multiple actors using the same object (library) might block the concurrency from actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple actors calling a function in an `object` that calls a library will not block unless the library being called uses concurrency control mechanisms such as `sychronized`, `ThreadLocal` or an object lock.

For example, calling `print` on the below `Printer` object will block:

```
class BlockingPrinter(){
  def print(s: String) = synchronized{s}
}

object Printer{
  val printer = new BlockingPrinter()

  def print(str: String) = printer.print(str)
}
```

But calling it on the below `Printer` object will not

```
class NonBlockingPrinter(){
  def print(s: String) = s
}

object Printer{
  val printer = new NonBlockingPrinter()

  def print(str: String) = printer.print(str)
}
```

In summary, the library that you're calling is the one that decides how concurrency is handled. Not the fact that you're calling an object.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the function is implemented. If the function accessed some internal mutable state and tries to synchronize in order to achieve thread safety then there is a problem. If it's a pure function and does not access any external state, then it is safe. If the function has the mutable state at least it must contain the mutable state to itself.